# DiscretePlot with a List as argument

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, functions

Suppose I have some multidimensional function that is computationally very expensive to evaluate. Here, I will just use

```
ExpensiveFunction[x_] := 0.01*{3*x, -x^2, 0.1*x^3};
```

I want to make a discrete plot that looks like this:

```
DiscretePlot[
{ExpensiveFunction[x][[1]], ExpensiveFunction[x][[2]], ExpensiveFunction[x][[3]]}, 
{x, 0, 10, 1}, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"Blue", "Orange", "Green"}]
```

[image: DiscretePlot 1]

However, I want to call `ExpensiveFunction` as few times as possible. Thus, I write equivalently (or so I thought):

```
DiscretePlot[ExpensiveFunction[x],
{x, 0, 10, 1}, Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"Blue", "Orange", "Green"}]
```

[image: Discrete Plot 2]

Obviously, this is not the same, and the coloring and the labels are messed up.

I do not understand: Why is this not equivalent to the first plot? What is the difference between `{ExpensiveFunction[x][[1]], ExpensiveFunction[x][[2]], ExpensiveFunction[x][[3]]}` and `ExpensiveFunction[x]`? And how can I reproduce the first plot without calling `ExpensiveFunction` too often?

Comment: Use `Evaluate`. That is `ExpensiveFunction[x_] = 0.01*{3*x, -x^2, 0.1*x^3};
DiscretePlot[ExpensiveFunction[x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10, 1}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"Blue", "Orange", "Green"}]`

Comment: @cvgmt Wow, that works, thank you! But why does ```Evaluate``` make any difference here? It seems a bit counterintuituve to me that the same object is treated so differently depending on when exactly it is evaluated (either by ```Evaluate``` or by ```DiscretePlot```). And also, why does my first plot behave so differently from the second one then?

Comment: Plotting functions such as `DiscretePlot` have the attribute `HoldAll`. Since the argument is initially held, it is seen as a single object. Using `Evaluate` forces immediate evaluation and the argument is seen as a list of three elements.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, that answers my questions!